# Nginx "Proxy_Cache" Configuration Help Needed

Tags: nginx

I'm running in to a really weird issue. I only want to enable Proxy Cache for "new-site.com". However, when doing so, Nginx is proxy caching all of my websites.

I've went through all my vhost / config files and made sure that all "http" and "server" blocks were opened and closed correctly. It's my understanding that Proxy_Cache is only enabled for a site when you include (for example) "proxy_cache  new-site;" in your websites "server" block.

In my "http" block, I load all of my websites .conf  files, but none of them include any proxy_cache directives.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a snippet of my config file :

```
http {
     ...
     ...

     # nginx cache
     proxy_cache_path  /www/new-site.com/httpdocs/cache levels=1:2
                       keys_zone=new-site:10m
                       max_size=50m
                       inactive=1440m;
     proxy_temp_path   /www/new-site.com/httpdocs/cache/tmp 1 2;    

     # virtual hosting
     include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*.conf;
}
```

Then here is my "new-site.com" vhost conf file:

```
server {

     listen          xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;

     server_name     new-site.com;

     root            /www/new-site.com/httpdocs;
     index           index.php;

     ...
     ...

     proxy_cache  new-site;

     location / {
         try_files $uri @backend;
     }

    location ~* \.php {

         include /usr/local/etc/nginx/proxypass.conf;

         proxy_ignore_headers  Expires Cache-Control;
         proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_502;
         proxy_cache_bypass  $cookie_session $http_secret_header;
         proxy_no_cache  $cookie_session;
         add_header X-Cache  $upstream_cache_status;
         proxy_cache_valid 200 302 5m;
         proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
         proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:80;
     }

     location @backend {
         include /usr/local/etc/nginx/proxypass.conf;

         proxy_ignore_headers  Expires Cache-Control;
         proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_502;
         proxy_cache_bypass  $cookie_session $http_secret_header;
         proxy_no_cache  $cookie_session;
         add_header X-Cache  $upstream_cache_status;
         proxy_cache_valid 200 302 5m;
         proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
         proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:80;
     }

     location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|css|js)$ {
         ....
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once I moved the line "proxy_cache  new-site;" in to a "location" block, that resolved the issue for me.

Not sure why I have this issue when it sits outside a block though.